# What is are these commands in square brackets doing in Vim?

Tags: vim

Doing a Vimgolf exercise that requires you to start with the following:

```
- One number per line -
-----------------------
2,3,5,7,
11,13,17,
19,23,29,
```

And then transform it to:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
```

One solution given is:

```
dj3gJV"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>pZZ
```

I'm following everything up to "=[", etc.  Doing ":help [" in Vim only reveals some movements with square brackets in normal mode.  I think the quotation mark indicates to use a special register, but I'm unclear on the rest of what follows after the equals sign.

1) What's a good way to query Vim's help system to get what's going on with "=[ ..." in visual mode?
2) And, can you explain what is going on with "=[ ..."? (where ... is an abbreviation for the rest of the commands that follow)

Comment: `:help "=` seems relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call 'expression register', put List of vim script language and evaluate it.

1. `"=` will call 'expression register'. If you put to this register vim-script language expression, it's will be computed.

`:help "=` for more information about expression register.

`:help <C-R>` for information about special registers.

2. `:help c_<C-R>_<C-A>` insert WORD under cursor. You in Visual mode, so all selection will be inserted.
3. `[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,]` this is a List of vim script language. `:help List`
4. As you can read in `:help "=`

   > If the result is a List each element is turned into a String and used as a line.